# My husband's visa refused but mine wasn't -- can I travel?

Tags: customs-and-immigration

My baby and I got a visa from the French embassy but my husband's visa was refused. Can anybody can tell me if I can travel or not because my child is 2.5 years old? One consultant told me that immigration can create  trouble for me because my child is too young, and how can I wondering with him (because purpose of visit is tourism).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "how can I wondering with him". Do you mean "how can I travel with him"? "Wonder" means to think about something ("I wonder if I would enjoy Paris"); maybe you meant "wander", which means to walk around with no particular goal ("I wandered the streets of Paris").

Comment: What is/are your nationalities?

Answer (score 12):

**If you and your baby have visas then you can travel.** It doesn't matter how young the child is.

The only complication is that you may need proof that the baby's father has given permission for them to travel. Usually this takes the form of a letter from the father giving permission to travel. Depending on circumstances it may need to be notarized.